# Are there Serilog SelfLog options other than Console.Out?

Tags: serilog

This is a rather simple question. I have only seen documentation showing one option for selflog i.e. to Console.Out as follows.

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Out = Console.Out
```

That is not an option for me where I plan to log from several remote servers. Is there a way to specify a name and location for a text file? Will Serilog itself log its debugging info in a structured manner? Any way to make this text file a rollover file?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: I noticed SelfLog.Out expects a TextWriter, so I did something like this.

Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Out = new System.IO.StreamWriter(File.Open(@"c:\temp\seriself.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite));

That did write error as expected. Does Serilog dispose of this object on each write to this file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any `System.IO.TextWriter` is supported. No, the writer is not flushed or disposed automatically - you'll need to handle this manually within the application code.